# Is it possible to sort a Table of Contents alphabetically

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents

I would like to sort the Table of Contents of a document alphabetically rather than by page number.

Suppose I have a Table of Contents automatically generated from headings like this one :

> **TABLE OF CONTENT**
>
> Updating your ToC..................................................1
>
> Creating a Table of Contents...................................3
>
> Deleting a ToC.........................................................4

I want it to look like :

> **TABLE OF CONTENT**
>
> Creating a Table of Contents...................................3
>
> Deleting a ToC.........................................................4
>
> Updating a Toc.........................................................1

Is this possible ?

**EDIT** : Thanks for your help so far. Seeing your answers, I realized that my previous example was confusing and looked indeed more as an Index.

I don't want to use an Index because afaik it can't be done automatically, for example by refering the Headings.

Also, the rest of the document must stay the same. The different parts (headings) can't be reorganized.

I tried to sort alphabetically the ToC with the Sort button, but it "doesn't work for fields".

Comment: So you essentially want to make an index from the table of contents? Technologies prefered? Format of table of contents?

Comment: Did you ever manage this? I am trying to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

An alphabetized ToC? Are you sure you don't just want an [index](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-build-an-index-in-word-2013.html)?  "An index is a reference list like a table of contents, but with more detail and at the opposite end of the document. Also, the index is organized by topic or keyword [i.e. alphabetically], as opposed to the organizational description a table of contents offers."

The other main difference is that a ToC can be automatically generated from headings as specified by styles, while an index's entries must be manually tagged.  If you're willing to hand tag your entries, the Insert... Index functionality may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer. I updated my question with a better example.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me from another user...

> In fact... It turns out that you CAN'T sort a Table of Contents unless
>   you unlink it (Ctrl+Shift+F9). Even if you lock the field, the sort
>   command gives an error ("Word cannot sort fields in the selection"),
>   at least in Word 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! By organizing your headings then updating the table of contents. Here are step by step instructions.

http://wordribbon.tips.net/T011238_Sorting_by_Headings.html

Comment: Hello - can you post the essentials here? If the link goes stale at some point in the future, your answer becomes worthless.

Answer (score 0):

This is in answer to the question of "how to convert a Table of Contents to alphabetical order" without going through all the bother about Indexes.

Steps:

- Have your list
- Click on Home
- Go to Styles
- Highlight each heading and click heading 1 (I have not tried this with lower headings but it should also work)
- Once they are all now headings go to the top of the page and click where you want the Contents List to be.
- Click on References and then go and click on Table of Contents under File on the top left-hand side.
- Then click on one of the two automatic tables in the drop-down menu. (I have only ever used the first one.)
- Now here is the tricky bit. Select all of the entries in the table of contents but not the heading of the table itself and highlight the headings and their page numbers in the document. You sort of have to sweep your cursor across the whole table.
- Once it is highlighted you now (and this is where the magic happens) click on the Insert Button at the top of the page usually third from the left.
- Then click on the drop down table. Make sure that before you do this the entries in the Contents Table are selected.
- Then move your cursor down and click on Convert Text to Table and its dialogue box will open.
  The number of columns box should be 1.
  The number of rows box should show the number of rows in your contents table, i.e. the number of entries.
- Leave the AutoFit behaviour on Fixed Column Width. (You could probably change it but I never have.)
- The “Separate text at” selection I leave at “Paragraphs”.
- Then click OK.
  This will put each entry into its own wide cell row
- NOW, select all the rows again but nothing more (this is  where people go wrong) and go to Home and click on the alphabet button which is the blue A above the black Z with the arrow pointing downwards on the right hand side. It is usually under where the word Review is.
- You should get a Sort By button. It will have defaulted to the name which is the first entry. Change that to Column 1 in the Sort column (this is also where you can go wrong) and then hit OK.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.